# Embeddable paste tool

Tags: html

I need a full-page embeddable paste tool. I have seen a couple websites where they have something similar to http://pastie.org for their staff, and can paste code, write down notes, and put down announcements to the staff, as if it was a different website, and only displays text files made by users through that particular site. Is there a software I can use like this?

EDIT: Can use Javascript, PHP, whatever. (If it's easy to implement)

Comment: There might be, but what technology is required by you? Should it be using PHP, Python, Java, ...? Solutions might very much depend on what you can handle :) Also: Do you want to host that "Pastebin" yourself, or rather use an existing paste-bin service? Or maybe both are acceptable solutions? May I suggest you [edit] your question and add those details? Thanks!